# Is it possible to create a Groovy package that can be used in a script without compilation?

Tags: groovy

I'm using groovy as a stand-alone scripting language (not compiling it) and am struggling with how
to structure multiple files with the `package` keyword but still be able to `import` them in other
files. An example of this would be the following:

Directory structure:

```
+-- Project
    +-- Example.groovy
    +-- ExampleTest.groovy
```

With the current setup, without any `package` keywords I can have the following:

```java
// Example.groovy
class Example {
    String message

    def Example(input = "placeholder") {
        this.message = input
    }
}

//ExampleTest.groovy
import Example

class ExampleTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testInitialiserWithoutArg() {
        def object = new Example()
        assertEquals(object.message, "placeholder")
    }

    void testInitialiserWithArg() {
        def object = new Example("test")
        assertEquals(object.message, "test")
    }
}
```

With this, I can add a script in the project directory to use the example class or run the tests
on the commandline with `groovy ExampleTest.groovy` (groovy bin is in PATH).

How do I then go about putting the `Example` class into a package so that a script can import the 
example class and I can run the unit tests on commandline? eg:

```
+-- Project
    +-- some
    |   +-- random
    |       +-- main
    |       |   +-- Example.groovy
    |       +-- test
    |           +-- ExampleTest.groovy
    +-- UseExample.groovy
```

I added `package some.random` to both `Example.groovy` and `ExampleTest.groovy` but even with 
`Example.groovy` and `ExampleTest.groovy` just in the `/Project/some/random` directory, I can't 
seem to work out how to `import` the `Example` class in `ExampleTest.groovy` to run the tests from
the commandline or how to import the whole `some.random` package in a separate script like 
`UseExample.groovy`.

Is this possible or do I have to compile the package before I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daggett's answer worked but required all additional libraries that were `import`ed (and available in groovy) be added to the `classpath` list. I then found that the `groovy` executable also has a `classpath` argument so the following is a simplified version of Daggett's answer for when groovy scripts aren't being run with the `java` executable:

```
groovy -classpath "./path/to/ExampleClass.groovy" ./scriptThatUsesExampleClass.groovy
```

I also noticed that the classpath needs to point to the top directory of a package eg:

```
+-- Project
    +-- main
    |   +-- my
    |       +-- example
    |           +-- ExampleClass.groovy
    +-- test
    |   +-- my
    |       +-- example
    |           +-- TestExampleClass.groovy
    +-- UseExampleClass.groovy
```

Where `UseExampleClass.groovy` contains `import my.example.ExampleClass`, the java command would be:

```
path\to\Project:
> java -classpath %GROOVY_HOME%\lib\*;main groovy.ui.GroovyMain UseExampleClass.groovy
```

And for the groovy binary:

```
path\to\Project:
> groovy -classpath main UseExampleClass.groovy
```

Using `-classpath main\my\example` resulted in `unable to resolve class my.example...`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to config your ide to start/test your project. if you want to do it as `bin/groovy` then here is a simple command line:

```
java.exe -classpath ".\embeddable\groovy-all-2.4.11.jar;.\my\test;.\my\main" groovy.ui.GroovyMain .\my\test\pack\Test.groovy
```

where:

- .\embeddable\groovy-all-2.4.11.jar

  path(s) to groovy libs
- .\my\test

  path to your test classes/scripts
- .\my\main

  path to your main classes/scripts
- groovy.ui.GroovyMain

  groovy script launcher/loader
- .\my\test\pack\Test.groovy

  your entry point script that will be executed. 
  even it is in classpath you have to specify full or relative to current directory path.

file struct:

- my

  - main

    - pack

      - A.groovy
  - test

    - pack

      - Test.groovy

A.groovy

```
package pack

public class A{
    def f(p){
        println p
    }
}
```

Test.groovy

```
package pack

new A().f("hello")
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain in a little more detail what the command is doing? I'm guessing it is telling java where to look for things before it tries to run the script with groovy?

Comment: @inkychris, everything should work. just check that folder names corresponds to package name. the groovy class  with `package my.super.package;` should be located in the relative to classpath folder `my/super/package`